# Getting NGINX "failed (111: Connection refused) while proxying and reading from upstream, udp"

Tags: nginx

I have an existing reverse proxying of http/https and I wanted to add raw tcp/udp stream.
Using Module ngx_stream_core_module I added this config:

```
stream {
    upstream app-udp{
       server 192.168.165.10:50000 max_fails=0;
    }

    upstream app-tcp{
       server 192.168.165.10:50001 max_fails=0;
    }

    server {
        listen  192.168.134.20:6653 udp;
        preread_buffer_size 16k;
        preread_timeout 30s;
        proxy_protocol_timeout 30s;
        proxy_timeout 10m;
        proxy_pass "app-udp";
    }

    server {
        listen  192.168.134.20:6654;
        preread_buffer_size 16k;
        preread_timeout 30s;
        proxy_protocol_timeout 30s;
        proxy_timeout 10m;
        proxy_pass "app-tcp";
    }
}
```

On the backend I set up an echo service just to bounce back the packets as replay.
Testing TCP works great with sending and getting response all the way.
UDP however is failing on the response from the echo service to NGINX.
Wireshark shows:

> "ICMP: icmp destination unreachable port unreachable"

The nginx error log shows:

> "*352 recv() failed (111: Connection refused) while proxying and
> reading from upstream, udp client: 192.168.165.10, server:
> 192.168.134.20:6653, upstream: "192.168.165.10:50000", bytes from/to client:35/0, bytes from/to upstream:0/35"

I couldn't find any reference online to this type of error from NGINX...
What could be the problem? Have missed some configuration on NGINX of perhaps issue with the network on the backend side? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i had exactly the same problem. Then i added `proxy_responses 0;`  to the configuration and the error disappeared.

```sh
stream {
    upstream app-udp{
       server 192.168.165.10:50000 max_fails=0;
    }

    upstream app-tcp{
       server 192.168.165.10:50001 max_fails=0;
    }

    server {
        listen  192.168.134.20:6653 udp;
        preread_buffer_size 16k;
        preread_timeout 30s;
        proxy_protocol_timeout 30s;
        proxy_timeout 10m;
        proxy_pass "app-udp";
        proxy_responses 0;
    }

    server {
        listen  192.168.134.20:6654;
        preread_buffer_size 16k;
        preread_timeout 30s;
        proxy_protocol_timeout 30s;
        proxy_timeout 10m;
        proxy_pass "app-tcp";
        proxy_responses 0;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps